# Is using PHP to loop a mySQL query efficient?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a HTML table full of check-boxes on page 1 with the name attribute set like this:

input type="checkbox" name="A_1"
input type="checkbox" name="B_2"

**On the following page, I loop through my $_POST array in PHP with explode to make an array like this:**

Array ( [A_1] => on [A_2] => on [B_2] => on [B_5] => on [C_5] => on [submit] => Submit )

**Into two arrays:**

row_Array = Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 5 [4] => 5 )

column_Array = Array ( [0] => A [1] => A [2] => B [3] => B [4] => C )

**This is my SQL query:**

```
for($i=0; $i < count($column_array); $i++) {
    $sql =  "SELECT {$column_array[$i]} FROM table WHERE num IN ({$row_array[$i]})";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $result_array[] = $data[$column_array[$i]];
    }
}
```

**Here is an example of my SQL table:**

```
  A   B   C
1 cat cot cet
2 rat rot ret
3 hat hot het
4 lat lot let
5 bat bot bet
```

**The individual SQL queries from my loop look like this and return the correct values:**

```
SELECT A FROM table WHERE num IN (1) returns cat
SELECT A FROM table WHERE num IN (2) returns rat
SELECT B FROM table WHERE num IN (2) returns rot
SELECT B FROM table WHERE num IN (5) returns bot
SELECT C FROM table WHERE num IN (5) returns bet
```

I am quite new to sql and php. This works but it seems like a terrible way to do this. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What seems so bad about it?

Comment: Where did the original numbers come from anyway? It might need to be converted to a join.

Answer (score 6):

I believe it's a better practice to run a single query and loop through the data returned rather than looping and then running multiple queries.

However, depending on your data structure and application layout, UI, etc, that may not be possible.

Answer (score 3):

I would aim for something like `SELECT A,B,C,num FROM table WHERE num IN (1,2,5)`

then maybe

```
foreach($result as $r){
    $data[$r['num']] = $r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try just running one query and loop trough it. It's pretty much @Andy Gee 's answer expressed in code.

```
$cols = implode(',', array_unique($column_array));
$rows = implode(',', array_unique($row_array));

$sql =  "SELECT {$cols} FROM table WHERE num IN ({$rows})";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //Do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like, it's realy bad idea but..:

```
$columns = implode(', ', $column_array);
$num_values = implode(', ', $row_array);
$sql =  "SELECT {$columns}, num FROM table WHERE num IN ({$num_values})";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $result_array[] = $data[$column_array[$i]];
}
```

Other way is to build one long Query with UNION

```
SELECT A as value, num FROM table WHERE num = 1
UNION
SELECT A as value, num FROM table WHERE num = 2
UNION
SELECT B as value, num FROM table WHERE num = 2
UNION
SELECT B as value, num FROM table WHERE num = 5
UNION
SELECT C as value, num FROM table WHERE num = 5
```

returns:

```
array(
   array("num" => 1, "value" => 'cat'),
   array("num" => 1, "value" => 'rat'),
   ...
);
```